# LocationManager not working on Android phone

Tags: android, locationmanager

I have a problem,

The locationmanager is working perfectly fine when i test it in the emulator and edit the location in the DDMS screen, but when i test it on the **Samsung Galaxy SII**, its nog working..

Please help me.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LbsGeocodingActivity extends Activity {

    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // in Meters
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    protected Button retrieveLocationButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, new MyLocationListener());

        retrieveLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCurrentLocation();
            }
        });        
    }    

    public String getMyPhoneNumber(){
        TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
        mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        return mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
    }

    protected void showCurrentLocation() {

        Location location =   locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (location != null) {
            String message = String.format("Current Location \n  Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s \n %3$s ", location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude(), getMyPhoneNumber());
            Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }   

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        String message = String.format(
                "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s \n  %3$s ",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude(),   getMyPhoneNumber()
        );
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, message,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,
                "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,
                "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
}
```

In the permissions i have:

`ACCES_COURSE_LOCATION`
`ACCES_FINE_LOCATION`

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are you getting an error? Is the altitude always `0`? Are you working at the beach?

Comment: No, it just doesn't call the function. When i turn off the GPS it gives the Toast. But it never gives the toast of the LocationManager..

Comment: "doesn't call the function", what function?? be more specific.

Comment: Well if i test it on the phone, the only Toast i get is when i turn my GPS on and off. Even when i quote the                   location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude(),   getMyPhoneNumber()
it doesn't work on the mobile device. But when i test it on the Emulator it works perfectly fine. Sorry i'm not that good in Android Programming. I hope this is enough

Comment: `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` this returns `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a problem with your incorrect usage of `String.format()`. Sometimes this can cause weird, device-specific issues. Try,

```
String lon = "" + location.getLongitude();
String lat = "" + location.getLatitude();
String num = getMyPhoneNumber();

String message = String.format(
    "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s \n %3$s",
    lon,
    lat,
    num
);
```

---

Have you tried using this?

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)act.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria crit = new Criteria();
crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
String provider = lm.getBestProvider(crit, true);
Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

Comment: No sorry, still no Toast appears in the screen.. What could be the problem that it works on the emulator, but not on the phone... The GPS is turned on on the samsung galaxy SII

Comment: so does that mean that `Location location` is returning `null` then? Are you sure about this?

Comment: Ehm, no i just don't get any Toast. It's not returning anything. How can i test if it's returning null?

Comment: `if (location == null) Log.v("Activity", "loc is null");`

Comment: I tested it again, with the Log in it. and the second part of code you gave me. It still didn't work. If you want to i can send the code to you, so that you can test it yourself?

Comment: I don't have a device to test with... only the emulator, so that wouldn't really work probably. I think your best bet is to just google search "`getLastKnownLocation` returns null" or something like that... sorry -_- (i've never used `locationmanager` before)

Comment: Oke thank you for your help. If by any chance you find something. Please let me know. Anyway thanx for your help

Comment: Perhaps you could play around with the `MININIMUM` integer constants... try different values and see if they work? This is only an idea that I had from a couple of the short answers I saw online... good luck though. I'll let you know if i think of anything else. Usually it is the emulator that has trouble, not the device... so this is definitely a weird issue.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you are testing indoors, and can't get any GPS information.
Try to change `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER-->LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER.`

Comment: Such a simple explanation, but I was struggling to figure out why all of the sudden this wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

i had similar issues using the locationmanager on my HTC incredible S running 4.0.4.
it would simply stop firing location changes on the real device after some time.
on some other devices it would work.
very intermittent.

my solution was to piss off the LocationManager and use LocationClient pardiagm.
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html

ever since google play services have been introduced the Locationmanager has been intermittent on my device. I cant give any other explanation as to why it occurs.

But the LocationClient works everytime plus it removes the dumb 'provider' notion from location management.