# Android - GPS after a while no longer receives coordinates

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I have a big problem with an Android application that I developed.

The purpose of the application (for business) is to track the position of the device continuously (24 hours on 24) detecting a GPS track on a regular interval, which will then be synchronized to the server to the unleashing of certain events.

Of course, over time the device in and out of buildings, acquiring and losing the GPS signal continuously.

Often the device is not used and remains in office for several hours inside the company headquarters without GPS signal. During the course of time the Android system continues to provide me constantly getLastKnowLocation

My problem is that after some time that the system is running, sometimes two or three days, sometimes more days, my app starts to receive from the system always the same coordinates, regardless of who is in the open or at closed. From what I understand the Android operating system no longer seems able to update his coordinates and It will always return the same **getLastKnowLocation** indefinitely.

My App therefore becomes useless.

You know how I can fix this?
Is there any process that Android can restart in order for the system to wake up. In My App I will acquire any permission, except for root permissions.

For now the only control that I put, and that if the system always gives me the same identity for a number of seconds I call the method **requestLocationUpdates** of the location manager again.

But I need something more robust, to give me a better guarantee of operation. I'd like to be sure as possible that the systems try really to get updated coordinates.
The only thing I can think of is that maybe I can ask the system to restart some process so that the Location Manager, is fully reset. Can I do this? What is the process to be killed?

Can you think of any other solution or you found yourselves in this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the Google Play Service Location API available to you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18993966/295004 http://stackoverflow.com/a/17150385/295004